# How to I trigger Xdebug 3.x with Drush in PHPStorm

Tags: drush, debugging

Has anyone has success with getting CLI debugging (**drush**) working with Xdebug 3.x?
There are several obsolete posts here... but all obsolete with the new version of Xdebug.

**Expected behavior**

After setting a breakpoint in a PHP class or module, that I know is executed when a specific Drush command is run, I would like PHPStorm to stop at the breakpoint.

Debugging when initiated from the browser works beautifully.
Drush - nothing.
Though it used to before I;

1. upgraded to Catalina
2. upgraded Xdebug from 2.x to 3.x

**Environment:**

Local MAMP Drupal 8 / Drush 9.7.2

**PHP**

PHP 7.4.13 (cli) (built: Nov 30 2020 14:46:04) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
with Zend OPcache v7.4.13, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am guessing that you have changed your xdebug.ini according to the new standards. (Port changed from 9000 to 9003 etc...)

If not you should do that first.
Check [this link](https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide) for additional information on the matter.

Besides that considering that you are using phpstorm, you should simply run

```
export XDEBUG_SESSION=PHPSTORM
```

before running the drush command. This must be done once every time you open a new terminal session. (Not sure if there is a way to have it permanently and if there is i am not sure you want it.) Nevertheless, if your configurations are ok, this should work.

Best Regards.

Comment: Thank you. Just a comment or two. First, I don't think there is an xdebug.ini. 
According to the docs, the config will more likely be in `php.ini`

Also, in my case there was/is some configuration in `.bash_profile`.

Once I got the debugger to trigger, I saw another error referencing an old virtual host that I'm not using.  Fixed it with `export PHP_IDE_CONFIG="serverName=myhost-www.localhost"`

Comment: @sea26.2 – Can you maybe add another answer as well, with all the steps you did to fix it in the end?

Comment: Hey again, there is no xdebug.ini indeed, but any *.ini file you create will add up to your php configurations and it is advised to use separate files (At least I prefer it that way) to declutter the main php.ini file a bit.